# How to filter Boto3 s3 objects?

Tags: python, boto3

I want to change this line

```
   files = os.listdir('/Users/milenko/mario/Json_gzips')
```

in my code,to read `.gz` files from my bucket straight into list.
I tried

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
>>> s3
s3.ServiceResource()
>>> my_bucket = s3.Bucket('cw-dushpica-tests')

>>> for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='*.gz'):
...     print(object_summary)
```

There is no output,it does print nothing.

```
for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='/'):
...     print(object_summary)
```

The same,got nothing.

How should my prefix look like?

Comment: I think `Prefix` is like directory. You can getting all files and then try filtering. Check this please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python/14001395

Comment: @Dmitry What should I use for current dir?

Comment: Also check it please - https://devqa.io/download-s3-objects-python-boto3/

Answer (score 5):

The prefix parameter of the filter method means that

> Prefix (string) -- Limits the response to keys that begin with the specified prefix.

So, you can limit the path to the specific folder and then filter by yourself for the file extension.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('your_bucket')

keys = []

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='path/to/files/'):
    
    if obj.key.endswith('gz'):
        
        keys.append(obj.key)
        
print(keys)
```